# Can we merge both these tags [android-navigation-drawer] and [navigation-drawer]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Both the tags [navigation-drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigation-drawer) and [android-navigation-drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-navigation-drawer) are  used for [**`Navigation Drawer`**](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer):

- [navigation-drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigation-drawer)

  > The Android Navigation Drawer is a panel that transitions in/out from the edge of the screen and displays the app’s main navigation options.
- [android-navigation-drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-navigation-drawer)

  > The Android Navigation Drawer is a panel that transitions in/out from the edge of the screen and displays the app’s main navigation options.

I propose merging the tags [navigation-drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigation-drawer) and [android-navigation-drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-navigation-drawer), because *both* the tags are used for questions related to **`Android Navigation Drawer`**.

Questions tagged [navigation-drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigation-drawer): 3,994 questions (3847 are also belong to [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)).

Questions tagged [android-navigation-drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-navigation-drawer): 605 questions

Comment: A re-tag must be done prior to this. There are many questions tagged with [tag:navigation-drawer] that would not be correctly tagged as [tag:android-navigation-drawer] but would be better tagged as [tag:react-native-navigation-drawer]

Comment: There is also [tag:android-drawer] with 74 questions and no wiki/excerpt..